# Trait for counting related Laravel Models only hitting the DB if necessary

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm wondering if anything like the following already exists for Laravel? It's a trait I wrote called CarefulCount.

What it does: It returns a count of related models (using any defined relation), but only hits the DB if absolutely necessary. First, it tries two options to avoid hitting the DB, if the information is already available:

1. Was the count retrieved using `withCount('relation')` when the model was retrieved - i.e. does `$model->relation_count` exist? If so, just return that.
2. Has the relation been eager-loaded? If so, count the models in the Eloquent collection without hitting the DB, with `$model->relation->count()`.
3. Only then resort to calling `$model->relation()->count()` to retrieve the count from the DB.

To enable it for any model class, you simply need to include the trait with `use CarefulCount`. You can then call `$model->carefulCount('relation')` for any defined relation.

For example, in my application there is a `suburbs` table with a has-many relation to both the `users` table and `churches` tables (i.e. there can be many users and many churches in a single suburb). Simply by adding `use CarefulCount` to the `Suburb` model, I can then call both `$suburb->carefulCount('users')` and `$suburb->carefulCount('churches')`.

My use case: I've come across this a number of times - where I need a count of related models, but it's in a lower-level part of my application that may be called from several places. So I can't know how the model was retrieved and whether the count information is already there.

In those situations, the default would be to call `$model->relation()->count()`. But this can lead to the [N+1 query problem](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

In fact, the specific trigger came from adding Marcel Pociot's excellent [Laravel N+1 Query Detector](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-query-detector) package to my project. It turned up a number of N+1 query problems that I hadn't picked up, and most were cases when I had *already* eager-loaded the related models. But in my Blade templates, I use Policies to enable or disable deleting of records; and the `delete($user, $suburb)` method of my `SuburbPolicy` class included this:

```
return $suburb->users()->count() == 0 && $suburb->churches()->count() == 0;
```

This introduced the N+1 problem - and obviously I can't assume, in my Policy class (or my Model class itself), that the users and churches are eager-loaded. But with the `CarefulCount` trait added, that became:

```
return $suburb->carefulCount('users') == 0 && $suburb->carefulCount('churches') == 0;
```

Voila! Tinkering with this and checking the query log, it works. For example, with the users count:

- If `$suburb` was retrieved using `Suburb::withCount('users')`, no extra query is executed.
- Similarly, if it was retrieved using `Suburb::with('users')`, no extra query is executed.
- If neither of the above were done, then there is a `select count(*)` query executed to retrieve the count.

As I said, I'd love to know whether something like this already exists and I haven't found it (either in the core or in a package) - or whether I've plain missed something obvious.

Here's the code for my trait:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

trait CarefulCount
{
    /**
     * Implements a careful and efficient count algorithm for the given
     * relation, only hitting the DB if necessary.
     *
     * @param string $relation
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function carefulCount(string $relation): int
    {
        /*
         * If the count has already been loaded using withCount('relation'),
         * use the 'relation_count' property.
         */
        $prop = Str::snake($relation) . "_count";
        if (isset($this->$prop)) {
            return $this->$prop;
        }

        /*
         * If the related models have already been eager-loaded using
         * with('relation'), count the loaded collection.
         */
        if ($this->relationLoaded($relation)) {
            return $this->$relation->count();
        }

        /*
         * Neither loaded, so hit the database.
         */
        return $this->$relation()->count();
    }
}
```